# updating scope variables both in parent and child controller

Tags: angularjs

Consider the html is

```
<div ng-controller="parentCtrl">
//some content
   <div ng-controller="childCtrl">
      <div ng-show = "mycommonscopevar">show my message </div>
      //some content
</div>
</div>
```

in my parent controller, i am setting **"mycommonscopevar"** as false initially and then in some function i am setting **mycommonscopevar** as true. When i click on a tab , my child controller will get called , now i need to set that **mycommonscopevar** as false again. I mean switching from one controller to another the scope variable has to be reset. Is this possible? Could anyone help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope   add $rootScope to both controllers, declare your variable as $rootScope.mycommonscopevar = someValue;  $rootScope is common scope for ALL controllers

Comment: Thanks for your reply..but i am not sure i am missing out something or not. but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Child can access and change the parent controller scope by

```
// Consider Parent Controller
function Parent($scope) {
    $scope.Test = 'value';
};

function Child($scope,$rootScope) {
    $scope.$parent.Test = ' $scope.Test value of parent can be changed here';
    $scope.ofChild = 'anyvalue'; // Cannot be accessed by the parent
    $rootScope.ofChild = 'can be accessed byy all controllers';
};
```

But the parent cannot access directly , better you can use services or $rootScope

Comment: could you kindly give any example for both cases

Comment: Edited the answer please check it out

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the value of $scope.mycommonscopevar to true in your child (if they share the same scope) and it will be reflected in the parent scope as well.

Comment: sorry i am not clear. What you mean by if there share the same scope. i need to reset the value  when i switch from one controller to another. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Maybe you should read something about scopes in AngularJS first: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: If possible can you explain with some simple example